# styles and scripts not working in partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view (`asp.net-mvc`) that contains a few `dropdownlist`'s with the class ''chosen-select'. But somehow that class doesn't get applied. The `dropdownlist`'s are displayed/styled as 'normal'.

```
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form("Home", "Index").FormMethod(FormMethod.Post).Type(FormType.Horizontal).InputWidthMd(12)))
{
    @f.FormGroup().DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, Model.Currencies).Class("chosen-select")

    @f.FormGroup().ListBoxFor(model => model.CountryIds, Model.Countries).ShowValidationMessage(false).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "chosen-select" })

    @f.FormGroup().ListBoxFor(model => model.USStateIds, Model.USStates).Id("usStates").ShowValidationMessage(false).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "chosen-select" })

    @Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Text(Resources.Form.Save).Class("btn btn-primary").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "float:right;" })
}
```

This `partial view` is displayed in a dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chosen-select').chosen();
});
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but the jquery code and the styles are placed in the view that renders this `partial view`. It was on the same page as the `partial view` at first, but the jquery code and the css styles doesn't seem to do anything. That's why I relocated them (not sure if that's relevant either).

I'm rendering this `partial view` by the way, via an `AJAX` call.

Comment: Call `.chosen()` on the elements in the partial view _after_ they've been added to the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you are executing your jQuery on document ready and then rendering the partial view view AJAX afterwords, so the jQuery is never applied.  Try doing this to initialize chosen:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, how did I not think of that!?

Comment: Excellent work!  This worked on my kendo-ui tabstrip (with bootstrap).  I was having odd, UI elements out of place until I called activateTab within the ajaxComplete callback.