# How to pass data to partial view after reload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, partial

Controller:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class ExperimentalController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ReloadTest1()
    {
        string temp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ViewBag.Time = temp;
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult ReloadTest1Partial()
    {
        string temp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ViewBag.Time = temp;
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReloadTest1";
    string time = this.ViewBag.Time;
    ViewData["date"] = time;

    ViewBag.TheTitle = "test";
}

<h2>ReloadTest1</h2>

<select id="iSelect" name="iSelect" >
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>


<div id="myPartialViewContainer">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_ReloadTest1Partial", null, new ViewDataDictionary { {"vb", ViewBag}});}
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#iSelect').on('change', function () {
        $("#myPartialViewContainer").load('@(Url.Action("ReloadTest1Partial", "Experimental", null, Request.Url.Scheme))')
    })
</script>
```

Partial View:

```html
@{
    var vb = ((dynamic)ViewData["vb"]);
}

<div>
    <span>@vb.Time</span>
</div>
```

**What is not working:**

Passing the viewbag/viewdata directly from controller to partial view because mvc does not accept that to happen.

**What is working:**

from the above code you can see that the partial view gets the data ONCE with the Html.RenderPartial method and the viewbag passing down.
the reload does work on change of the selected object in the dropdown

**What is needed:**

I need to pass data to the partial view when it is reloaded or afterwards, this is mainly a test setup but i finally want to be able to update tables dependant on the select value.

If somone is able to give me a working example please do so.

Comment: Can you show your `ReloadTest1Partial` action?

Comment: in the controller already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

Controller:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RolloutTool.Controllers
{
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public class ExperimentalController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ReloadTest1()
        {
            var model = new RolloutTool.Models.ExperimentalViewModels.MyModel { Time = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
            string temp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            ViewBag.Time = temp;
            ViewData["Time"] = temp;
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult ReloadTest1Partial(string test)
        {
            var model = new RolloutTool.Models.ExperimentalViewModels.MyModel { Time = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
            string temp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            ViewBag.Time = temp;
            ViewData["Time"] = temp;
            return PartialView("_ReloadTest1Partial", model);
        }
        
        // GET: Experimental
        public ActionResult Experimental()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            ViewBag.TestValue = 10;
            string[] temp = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta" };
            ViewBag.names = temp;
            int temp2 = temp.Length;
            ViewBag.nameslength = temp2;

            return View();
        }

    }

}
```

View:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReloadTest1";
    string time = this.ViewBag.Time;
    ViewData["date"] = time;

    ViewBag.TheTitle = "test";

}

@model RolloutTool.Models.ExperimentalViewModels.MyModel

<h2>ReloadTest1</h2>

<select class="chosen-select" id="iSelect" name="iSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>

<div id="myPartialViewContainer">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_ReloadTest1Partial", Model);}
</div>


@Styles.Render(
  "~/content/chosen/chosen.css",
  "~/content/chosen/prism.css",
  "~/content/chosen/style.css",
  "~/content/bootstrap.css",
  "~/content/Site.css")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen/prism.js"></script>
<script>
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
        '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
        '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
        '.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
</script>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#iSelect').on('change', function () {
        getPartial();
    })
</script>
<script>
    function getPartial() {
        var tempSelect = document.getElementById("iSelect");
        var tempResult = tempSelect.options[tempSelect.selectedIndex].text;
        $.ajax({
            url: "ReloadTest1Partial",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'test' = tempResult}, //if you need to post Model data, use this
            success: function (result) {
                $("#myPartialViewContainer").html(result).find("select").each(function () {
                $(this).chosen({});
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
@{
    string time = "";
    string temp = "";
    if (ViewData["vb"] != null)
    {
        temp = "1";
        time = ((dynamic)ViewData["vb"]).Time;
    }
    else if (ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.Time != null)
    {
        temp = "2";
        time = ViewBag.Time;
    }
    else if (ViewData["Time"] != null)
    {
        temp = "3";
        time = (string) ViewData["Time"];
    }
}
@model RolloutTool.Models.ExperimentalViewModels.MyModel
<div>
    <span>@time</span>
    <span>@Model.Time</span>
    <span>@temp</span>
</div>

<select class="chosen-select"></select>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen/prism.js"></script>
```

This updates the partial view correctly AND reloads the chosen-select dropdowns. (see [styles and scripts not working in partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127447/styles-and-scripts-not-working-in-partial-view))

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you;re using `ViewBag` to set custom value, but in your view you are working with `ViewData` as well as referring to a different name (you're setting ViewBag's Time property in controller, but you expect ViewData's vb property in the view).

Change your view to expect model`:

```
@model MyModel
@{
    string time = "";
    if (ViewData["Time"] != null) 
    {
       time = ViewData["Time"];
    } 
}

<div>
    <span>@Model.Time</span>
</div>
```

And change you controller to pass it:

```
public ActionResult ReloadTest1()
{
    var model = new MyModel {Time = DateTime.Now.ToString()};
    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult ReloadTest1Partial()
{
    var model = new MyModel {Time = DateTime.Now.ToString()};
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

And you master view file will look like this:

```
@model MyModel
<div id="myPartialViewContainer">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_ReloadTest1Partial", model);}
</div>
```

And create your model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Time {get;set;}
}
```

As a side not, it's always preferable to use a strongly-typed `model` instead of `ViewBag` or `ViewData` as you can get compilation errors and IntelliSense

Comment: viewbag is **not** able to be passed from controller to **partial** view, that's exactly why I needed to pass it through the dictionary with the html.renderpartial

Comment: But the most right option will be to use the `model`

Comment: ViewData is **also** not able to be passed from controller to partial view, the time is not updating. But the html.renderpartial change does work. An example with a model would be nice. Main problem is that I can either get the data passing or the reloading working but both at the same time fail to happen.

Comment: I've added an example with model

Comment: when I add location.reload(); the time is updated with viewdata and model but it does reset all elements whcih is not what I want.

Comment: location.reload reloads the whole page, of course it will reset all the elements. What are yountrying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the partial view to show new content which I pass to it, but either it does not get the content or it updates not correctly, although the new content is actually given to it. Your answers helped me track down the problem so I guess I need to look further into the partial page updating and reloading.